# Facebook PHP api clears session and cookies on callback

Tags: php, facebook

I've been experimenting with the facebook php api lately and I've run into an issue that I can not solve or find the answer to anywhere.

Before getting a session with getUser() I set some SESSION variables and COOKIES to use after the callback. Once the user authenticates and/or logs in the SESSION variables and COOKIES that I've set are no longer there.

I am using httpd (with SSL) to do this. Is there something that goes on internally with the facebook php api that I am missing here? Much appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are calling session_start at the beginning of every page.

Comment: I've been. Hasn't seemed to make a difference.